# scan a splitted line of characters in C

Tags: c, scanf, gets

I have been struggling scanning the following line of textfile into a char matrix :
`O A B C D E T`

What i tried was this :

```
fscanf(ifs, "%c %c %c %c %c %c %c",
graphe->name[0][0], graphe->name[1][0], graphe->name[2][0], 
graphe->name[3][0], graphe->name[4][0], graphe->name[5][0],
graphe->name[6][0]
);
```

For information: `ifs` is the file pointer, and the .txt file is opening well.
I'm precising that name is a `char**` because i might replace the letters with words someday. Thus, the string length might need to be increased.

Name is a `char**` being allocated as:

```
graphe->name = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*graphe->ordre);
for(int i=0;i<graphe->ordre;i++){
    graphe->name[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
}
```

For some reason, this is not working, am I doing anything wrong? Are there better practices in order to accomplish the same task ?

Comment: If e.g. `graphe->name[0][0]` is a single `char`, then that `fscanf` call should cause the compiler to emit a warning. If it doesn't then enable more warning, and treat them as errors. And perhaps take some time to refresh how to use the `scanf` family of functions in your beginners book.

Comment: Why malloc individual `char`s? Why not just use a 1D string?

Comment: By the way, you have tagged your question with the `gets` tag. Why? You don't seem to use the `gets` function, and you should [never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: To build on @Dúthomhas comment, if you know there will always be six characters, why not define `name` as a plain array of size elements, as in `char name[6]`?

Comment: And *always* check what `scanf` and family [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: I'm reading the name of nodes for a graph, this is why i have to read all of them seperately.

Comment: @Pianissimo What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding optimisations and recommandation given, I found out putting a space before the first %c solved the thing : `fscanf(ifs, " %c %c %c %c %c %c %c",xxx)`

Comment: `fscanf` won't read the ending newline. It will be left in the file for the next input operation. And `%c` will not skip white-space (like most other formats), and newline is a white-space character. Adding an explicit space in the format string will ask all `scanf` functions to skip white-space.

Comment: Better `char line[1024];` and then read every line and parse with `sscanf()`, e.g. `while (fgets (line, sizeof line, ifs)) { if (sscanf (line, " %c %c %c %c %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c ...) == 7) { /* you have good input in a, b, c, ... */ } }`